# Infinite loop when setState inside Firebase AuthStateChange

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to store the Firebase collection as a state so I can map it and display each user.  I am using onAuthStateChange so I don't get the uid undefine error when the page is refreshed.  Any idea why setting a state inside onAuthStateChanged would cause an infinite loop?  The onAuthStateChange shouldn't be listening to the changes in React states, but rather changes in user states such as logged in or logged out right?

```
// userHome.js - infinite loop

export default function(){
  const [userCollection, setUserCollection] = useState();

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(isUser => {
    if (isUser) {
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      const userRef = db.collection("user").doc(currentUser.uid);
      setUserCollection(userRef);
    }
  });
}
```

```
// Auth.js

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs everytime auth state changes
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      user.getIdTokenResult().then(IdTokenResult => {
        user.adminRole = IdTokenResult.claims.adminRole;
        user.shopRole = IdTokenResult.claims.shopRole;
        user.userRole = IdTokenResult.claims.userRole;
      });
      console.log("user state changed");
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentUser
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is that your complete `userHome.js` component? You don't have a return statement? Can you post your full component? And where are you consuming the `AuthContext`, specifically `currentUser`?